# Render new template contain successfully message after resetting password

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using `Fosuserbundle` and I want to  render new template contain successfully message after resetting password. but I don't know how can I override the ResettingController file in order to render the template. here is the controller :

```
public function resetAction(Request $request, $token)
{
    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.resetting.form.factory');
    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

    if (null === $user) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with "confirmation token" does not exist for value "%s"', $token));
    }

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();

    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $form->getErrors(true);



    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS, $event);
        $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Resetting:reset.html.twig', array(
            'token' => $token,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Resetting:reset.html.twig', array(
        'token' => $token,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html

Comment: this controller contains events, so if I want to render template I have to override listener,controller ... can you provide some examples ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using FosUserBundle and I'm not sure your code snippet abow is origin Fos controller. In your case, I don't think you needs to override the controller. Just listen to `FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS` event, create your own response and set back to the event `$event->setResponse($response)`, your response will be used by Fos controller. When create your response, you can render any template path with any parameters as you want.

Here is an example:

```
class ResettingListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EngineInterface
     */
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS => 'onResettingResetSuccess'];
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onResettingResetSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $this->templating->render('YourBundle:Location:resetting.html.twig', [
            'form' => $event->getForm()->createView()
        ]);

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

And register as service:

```
<service id="your_bundle.listener.resetting" class="Vendor\YourBundle\EventListener\ResettingListener">
    <argument type="service" id="templating" />
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
</service>
```